# If without else

Tags: syntax, conditional

The syntax for `If` is:

```
If[condition, then, else]
```

Which is the correct syntax for the case in which there is no `else`?

Comment: ? - "`If[condition,t]` gives `Null` if condition evaluates to `False`."

Comment: `If[condition, then, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]` or `If[condition, then, ##&[]]`?

Comment: What is the expected output if `condition` is false? `Null`?

Comment: In my case, If the condition is true the program exits the loop, agile If it is false it ramains in the loop.

Comment: @mattiav27 so what about the line I quoted from details section?

Answer (score 3):

It is formally correct, but if value of condition is `False`, then the output is `Null`

```
f[x_] := If[x > 0, 1.]
f[10]
```

`1.`

```
f[-1]
```

(Nothing)

```
f[-1] // FullForm
```

`Null`